# Looking to Create a Macro for Printing Addresses to Envelopes

Tags: vba, ms-word, envelope

First question on here, so hopefully I have followed all the guidelines etc.

I am looking to create a macro for a Word document which prints a headed paper copy, a yellow paper copy and an envelope (based on the address section of the letter). I have the paper copies sorted but I am having difficulty with the envelope.

My understanding is I should be able to use a field, where the address would be typed in and then use the field in the macro to print the envelope out. I have the envelope printing side of this sorted too, in that I can get an envelope to print from the document, just not get it to print only the address.

Whenever I use fields it does not seem to allow me to type into it, it just deletes it out. I have never used Fields before, so this may be something very simple I am missing. Based on some Youtube videos I watched it looks like MacroButton is the field I need to be using?

If anyone was able to assist me in how to use fields for this it would be greatly appreciated.

Currently my code only includes the printing side of things (envelope currently not included):

```
Sub OrCo()
'
' OrCo Macro
'
'
With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
.FirstPageTray = 259
.OtherPagesTray = 259
End With

Application.PrintOut FileName = "", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, _
Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:=wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, 
PrintToFile:=False

With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
.FirstPageTray = 260
.OtherPagesTray = 260
End With

Application.PrintOut FileName = "", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, _
Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:=wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, 
PrintToFile:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add your code to the post

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) Please have a read here to create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people answer your question, and review the following [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck.

Comment: @Kubie I have added the code I have so far. As I was having issues with getting fields to actually work I had not yet tried to add them into the code yet.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at the ask field as this field links the entered text to a bookmark which makes it easier to access the entered text from vba.

[MS help for the Ask field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-ask-field-31b8d920-978c-4aba-9dd7-68dd81ffd943?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

This if you have an ask field of the form

{ask street "Enter the street name"}

then from VBA you would be able to access the text using

activedocument.bookmarks("street").range.text

NOTE:  The ask field does not display the entered text.  To do that you need to add a separate ref field (or field containing just the bookmark name).  This allows you to put the ask fields anywhere you like and use multiple ref fields to display the result.

You may also want to review the envelope printout method.

[MS help for  the envelope printout method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.envelope.printout)

Good luck with your endeavors.